# Pandas monthly resample maintaining first date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

when resampling a time series into a monthly series, pandas changes the initial date of my time series with the start of the month. From:

```
2020-01-12    0.730439  
2020-01-13    0.559328    
                ...    
2021-06-29    0.188461  
2021-06-30    0.750668
```

To:

```
2020-01-01     8.613978
2020-02-01    14.614601
   ...              ...
2021-05-01    11.936765
2021-06-01    13.758198
```

Instead of the desired result, where in the fisrt month the date is the first date of my time series:

```
2020-01-12     8.613978
2020-02-01    14.614601
   ...              ...
2021-05-01    11.936765
2021-06-01    13.758198
```

Is there a way to perform a monthly resample without losing the initial date?

Currently I do correct it afterwards. I am asking if there is a way to do it on the fly. I have tried with all `resample`'s parameters without achieving the desired result. I had a look at `pd.Grouper` but also without success.

Thank you,
Gonxo

PS: Small script to replicate the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import random

index = pd.date_range('20200112', '20210630')
df = pd.Series(random(len(index)), index=index)

df.resample('MS').sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a manual update:

```
s = df.resample('MS').sum()

s.index = [df.index.min()] + list(s.index[1:])
```

Output:

```
2020-01-12     7.345615
2020-02-01    15.873136
2020-03-01    14.083565
2020-04-01    17.547765
2020-05-01    15.321236
2020-06-01    11.787999
2020-07-01    16.619211
2020-08-01    17.292133
2020-09-01    16.866571
2020-10-01    17.772687
2020-11-01    13.371602
2020-12-01    17.037126
2021-01-01    15.907105
2021-02-01    13.887159
2021-03-01    13.660123
2021-04-01    16.534306
2021-05-01    15.055836
2021-06-01    15.818617
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is cleaner to what I currently do. But I was asking if there is a way using resample itself or maybe other method like groupby, or using a Goruper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.close.resample('M').sum()
```

Alternatively, you can change 'MS' to 'M' in your code.

Comment: Hey Prafya, thank you for your answer. 'M' will provide the end of the month of all months. It will also not keep the desired date but put the end of month instead.